# Intersection of lines in barycentric coordinates

Tags: geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Consider a barycentric coordinate system with points $v_0,v_1,v_2$ and $x=\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2$ and $y=\beta_0 v_0 + \beta_2 v_2$.

Find the intersection $s$ of the lines through $x$ and $y$ and through $v_0$ and $v_1$.

I have the parametric forms:

$g_1(t)=x+t(y-x)=(0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)+t((\beta_0,0,\beta_2)-(0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2))=(0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)+t(\beta_0,-\alpha_1,\beta_2-\alpha_2)$
$g_2(u)=v_0+u(v_1-v_0)=(1,0,0)+u((0,1,0)-(1,0,0))=(1,0,0)+u(-1,1,0)$

For the second form I thought that $v_0$ is exactly one times itself and zero times the other points and the same for $v_1$.

When I set the equations equal and solve by component I don't really get a solution so I'm not sure if my approach is correct. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't understand your notations $x=\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2$ (Equ. 1) and $y=\beta_0 v_0 + \beta_2 v_2$ and I must not be alone because you haven't had any comment/answer. Why don't you have for example $x=\alpha_1 v_1 + (1- \alpha_1) v_2$ ? Otherwise said, equation (1) above makes sense only if $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=1$.

Comment: Yes they both add to $1$. Actually thanks to your tip I substituted $\alpha_2$ and was able to solve the equation.